# Cannot install package inside Dockerfile [E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)]

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to install a private package inside an Ubuntu 16.04 container. To do this, I am using the following line in a Dockerfile to build an image with base image Ubuntu 16.04 where `nf` is an argument set to various package names (repository addresses are not included):

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/init"]
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ARG nf
RUN touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cinar.list
RUN echo -e $"<repository addresses are here>" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cinar.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y $nf
```

The last line results with the following error:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/bash -c apt-get install -y $nf' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

However, when I remove this line from the Dockerfile and build the image, then go inside the container and use the command `apt-get install -y packagename`, this error does not occur. I would appreciate any help on this issue since I am doing an automation task and cannot manually install packages on containers. I have tried the solutions listed [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1), and none of them seems to work.

Comment: Is there more to the error message than that?  Where does the variable `$nf` come from, and is there any particular reason to use a shell variable rather than listing out the packages in the Dockerfile?

Comment: This is the entire error message. I added the complete Dockerfile. I am using this Dockerfile inside an Ansible playbook with different packages for building different images, which is why I am using the `nf` variable as a build argument.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, `$"repository-addresses"` is exactly the same as `repository-addresses`.

`repository-addresses` is not valid for entries in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list, nor is it a valid variable name.

If you have `repository-addresses` as build-arg, you should rename it to `repository_addresses` and use it with :

```
ARG repository_addresses
...
RUN echo -e "$repository_addresses" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cinar.list
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer my bad for not clarifying but I removed the repository addresses for privacy, they are added to the sourcelist normally.